# Android-AppWarp Unity SDK: BAD_REQUEST/CONNECTION_ERROR when calling WarpClient.GetInstance().Connect()

Tags: unity-game-engine, appwarp, app42

I'm running into the issues since today. The way I was keeping the user name unique was creating it as ${FACEBOOK_FIRST_NAME}_${FACEBOOK_ID} and WarpClient.GetInstance().Connect(${FACEBOOK_FIRST_NAME}_${FACEBOOK_ID}) worked just fine till now.
Today it stopped working, and after trial and error it seems that the username length is limited to 21 characters now. 22 characters user name causes CONNECTION_ERROR, 23 and more - BAD_REQUEST.
Is it a new restriction introduced, and if it is, what is the best way to maintain unique but readable user names based on users FB credentials? 
10x

Answer (score 1):

There are restrictions on the username string.

The length should be less than 25 and the following characters are not allowed

, ; \ /

See the API reference.

http://appwarp.shephertz.com/game-development-center/csharp-api-reference/#connect

Hope it helps.